# Making a color picker/eye dropper tool for drawing program in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I have a drawing program I am developing in VB. In the mousedownevent while a certain radiobutton is ticked, I want the mousedownevent handler to grab the color of the selected pixel that is clicked in a picturebox with an image. How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a `Bitmap` object and assign it to your PictureBox's image you can use the `GetPixel` method to get a pixel's color from the specified point.

```
Dim PickedColor As Color
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    PickedColor = DirectCast(PictureBox1.Image, Bitmap).GetPixel(e.X, e.Y)
End Sub
```

Comment: same error i have been getting: Parameter must be positive and < Width.
Parameter name: x

Comment: @BuddyRoach : If it solved your problem (as I see you use the code in the new code you posted) you should mark this as the answer by pressing the green tick below the vote count.

Answer (score 0):

Granted, I had interpolation mode set because this is a pixel editor and needed basic coloring for video game 8 bit design and antialiasing is not what i needed so this fixed it.

```
Dim COLOR1 as color
                    Dim x As Integer = 0
                    Dim y As Integer = 0
                    Dim Image1 As New Bitmap(picturebox1.Image, picturebox1.Width, picturebox1.Height)

                    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Image1)
                        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
                        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half
                        g.DrawImage(BackgroundImage1, 0, 0, Image1.Width, Image1.Height)
                    End Using

                    For x = 0 To picturebox1.Width
                    Next
                    For y = 0 To picturebox1.Height
                    Next
                    COLOR1 = New Bitmap(Image1).GetPixel(e.X, e.Y)
                    ColorDialog2.Color = COLOR1
                    PictureBox3.BackColor = COLOR1
```

But if you want this color picker without the interpolation pixel mode, so you can color pick on jpegs and whatnot, just take out the whole  using code. Works fine.

Comment: You don't need to use `New Bitmap(Image1)` since `Image1` already is a bitmap. Just do `Image1.GetPixel(...)`. Also, why do you have empty for-loops?